# Two queue manager with different channel not allowed

Tags: spring-boot, jms, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I use spring boot 2.3.2 with ibm mq.
I use property file setup mq.

```
ibm.mq.queueManager=
ibm.mq.channel=
ibm.mq.connName
ibm.mq.user
ibm.mq.password
ibm.mq.useIBMCipherMappings=false
ibm.mq.userAuthenticationMQCSP=false
ibm.mq.sslCipherSuite=TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
```

that works fine.

I need to create another factory to be able to connect to another channel. So I would like to create a similar one which is created by default but with different channel name.

So I created a config class

```
@EnableJms
@Configuration
public class JmsConfig {
@Bean
    public MQQueueConnectionFactory jmsMQConnectionFactoryPayment() throws JMSException {
        MQQueueConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setQueueManager("AD_TEST");
        connectionFactory.setChannel("FROM.PAYMENTMNG");
        connectionFactory.setConnectionNameList("wmqd1.int.test.com(1818),wmqd2.int.test.com(1818)");


        connectionFactory.setBooleanProperty(WMQConstants.USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP, false);

        connectionFactory.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_SSL_CIPHER_SUITE, "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256");
        connectionFactory.setIntProperty(CommonConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, CommonConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);


        System.setProperty("com.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings", String.valueOf(Boolean.FALSE));

        connectionFactory.createConnection("123", "123");
        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> jmsContainerFactoryPayment() throws JMSException {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(jmsMQConnectionFactoryPayment());
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean("payment")
    JmsTemplate jmsTemplatePayment() throws JMSException {
        JmsTemplate template = new JmsTemplate();
        template.setConnectionFactory(jmsMQConnectionFactoryPayment());
        return template;
    }


}
```

In a class I have

```
@JmsListener(destination="xxx", containerFactory="jmsContainerFactoryPayment"){
    ....
}
```

When I start application, I get

```
com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedIllegalStateException: JMSWMQ0018: E Failed to connect to queue manager 'AD_TEST' with connection mode 'Client' and host name 'wmqd1.int.test.com(1818),wmqd2.int.test.com(1818)'.

                at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.reasonToException(Reason.java:489) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.0.0.jar:9.2.0.0 - p920-L200710.DE]

                at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:215) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.0.0.jar:9.2.0.0 - p920-L200710.DE]

                at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConnection.<init>(WMQConnection.java:450) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.0.0.jar:9.2.0.0 - p920-L200710.DE]

                at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createV7ProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:8475) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.0.0.jar:9.2.0.0

Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ  call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') ; reason '2538' ('MQRC_HOST_NOT_AVAILABLE').

                at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:203) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.0.0.jar:9.2.0.0 - p920-L200710.DE]

                ... 51 common frames omitted
```

Seem like we can't have two queue manager with same host but different channel

Comment: MQRC_HOST_NOT_AVAILABLE means that the TCP/IP connection to the connection list you supplied could not be successfully made. Have you checked that you can ping the host names and that the listener is running?

Comment: yes is the one i use in the property file

Comment: Is that the same as the connection reported in the error message?

Comment: yes, also tried to use default connection (property file) and create a new one, get same result. I was not able to find any example on the web to get two queue manager with different config.

Comment: Sorry - I'm a little confused. Would it be possible for you to update the question showing both the original and the new details, i.e. the first connection (that works?) and the second connection where you have shown the failure. That might help to make it clear what is going wrong.

Comment: like it's already said, only thing that work it's when I use automatic config who use property file... any other combination: manual + manual or automatic + manual is not working

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, just making a single connection in a manual fashion does not even work?

Comment: If I have understood correctly, you would like to introduce another listener connected via different `Channel`. For this, you'll likely need to create a new `Connection Factory`. There is a discussion on that type of configuration [here](https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-jms-spring/issues/7) which might be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I have configured Spring Boot with IBM MQ to test this. Starting with the sample provided in this [IBM Messaging GitHub Repo](https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-jms-spring), I added two additional listeners as follows.

First I added some additional properties to the `application.properties` file

```
my.mq.queueManager=QM2
my.mq.channel=DEV.APP.SVRCONN
my.mq.connName=localhost(1415)
my.mq.user=<your_user_name>
my.mq.password=<your_password>
```

I left `Application.java` unchanged, copied `Listener.java` to create `ListenerTwo.java` and `ListenerThree.java`. I then added a new `ListenerBeanConfig.java` class to the sample.

`ListenerTwo.java` was changed to bind to a new `ConnectionFactory` configuration `listenerTwoFactory` which is created later.

```java
@JmsListener(destination = Application.qName, containerFactory = "listenerTwoFactory")
```

`ListenerThree.java` was changed to bind to a new `listenerThreeFactory` configuration and `Queue`

```java
@JmsListener(destination = "DEV.QUEUE.2", containerFactory = "listenerThreeFactory")
```

The `ListenerBeanConfig.java` class declaration was annotated so that I can access my properties by adding Strings for each property e.g., `queueManager`, `channel`, `connName` etc. and providing setter methods for each of them e.g.,

```java
@Configuration
@EnableJms
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="my.mq")
public class ListenerBeanConfig {

    String connName;
```

```java
public void setConnName(String value) {
    System.out.println("connName is set to: "+value);
    connName = value;
  }
```

I registered the two new `Listener` beans

```java
@Bean
  public ListenerTwo myListenerTwo() {
    return new ListenerTwo();
  }

@Bean
  public ListenerThree myListenerThree() {
    return new ListenerThree();
  }
```

I then created the new connection factory configurations `listenerTwoFactory` and `listenerThreeFactory`

For `listenerTwoFactory` I used the JMS classes provided by `com.ibm.mq.jms` in the Spring Boot config

```java
JmsConnectionFactory cf;

@Bean
  public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory listenerTwoFactory() {
  DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory containerFactory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
  try {
    JmsFactoryFactory ff = JmsFactoryFactory.getInstance(WMQConstants.WMQ_PROVIDER);
    cf = ff.createConnectionFactory();
    cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_NAME_LIST, connName);
    cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CHANNEL, channel);
    cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
    cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, queueManager);
    cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_APPLICATIONNAME, "Spring Boot ListenerTwo");
    cf.setBooleanProperty(WMQConstants.USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP, true);
    cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.USERID, user);
    cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.PASSWORD, password);
  } catch (JMSException jmsex) {
    System.out.println(jmsex);
  }
  containerFactory.setConnectionFactory(cf);
  return containerFactory;
}
```

For the `listenerThreeFactory` I used the MQ JMS helper classes from `com.ibm.mq.spring.boot`.

```java
@Bean
public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory listenerThreeFactory() {
    MQConfigurationProperties myProps = new MQConfigurationProperties();
    myProps.setUser(user);
    myProps.setChannel(channel);
    myProps.setConnName(connName);
    myProps.setPassword(password);
    myProps.setQueueManager(queueManager);
    //No customizer
    MQConnectionFactoryFactory mqcff = new MQConnectionFactoryFactory(myProps,null);
    MQConnectionFactory mqcf = mqcff.createConnectionFactory(MQConnectionFactory.class);
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory containerFactory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    containerFactory.setConnectionFactory(mqcf);
    return containerFactory;
}
```

Finally, I compiled and ran the new sample configuration. Using the IBM MQ Console for two IBM MQ queue manager docker instances, I put messages to `QM1: DEV.QUEUE.1` and `QM2: DEV.QUEUE.1, DEV.QUEUE.2`. On the terminal see the following output.

```
========================================
Received message is: message 1
========================================

========================================
ListenerTwo received message is: message 2
========================================

========================================
ListenerThree received message is: message 3
========================================
```

Also tested with all three listeners connected to QM2 via a two different channels: `DEV.APP.SVRCONN` and `DEV.APP.SVRCONN.TWO`.

I am sure there are far more elegant ways to manage the additional properties.